# Count frequency of value in column in dataframe in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I have a Spark dataframe with below schema:

```
root
 |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- matches: string (nullable = false)
```

which consist of values like

```
inf1 -> inf1, inf2, inf3,inf1, inf2, inf3
inf2 -> inf1, inf2, inf3,inf1, inf2, inf3
inf3 -> inf3, inf1, inf4
inf4 -> inf1, inf2, inf3,inf1, inf2, inf3,inf3, inf1, inf4
inf5 -> inf3, inf1, inf4
```

What is the best possible way to count frequency of words in matches column. O/P should be like :

```
inf1 -> {inf2: 2, inf3: 2}
inf2 -> ..
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `udf` to count the frequency 
create a `udf` as

```
val countFreq = udf((value: String) => 
  value.split(",").map(_.trim).groupBy(identity).mapValues(_.size)
)
```

create a new Column with the `udf` with `withColumn` function

```
val resultDF = df1.withColumn("matches", countFreq($"matches"))
resultDF.show(false)
```

Output:

```
+----+--------------------------------------------+
|name|matches                                     |
+----+--------------------------------------------+
|inf1|[inf2 -> 2, inf1 -> 2, inf3 -> 2]           |
|inf2|[inf2 -> 2, inf1 -> 2, inf3 -> 2]           |
|inf3|[inf1 -> 1, inf4 -> 1, inf3 -> 1]           |
|inf4|[inf2 -> 2, inf1 -> 3, inf4 -> 1, inf3 -> 3]|
|inf5|[inf1 -> 1, inf4 -> 1, inf3 -> 1]           |
+----+--------------------------------------------+
```

Final Schema is you get is Map

```
resultDF.printSchema()
root
 |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- matches: map (nullable = true)
 |    |-- key: string
 |    |-- value: integer (valueContainsNull = false)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks @Shankar. It's really helpful.

Comment: Is there a way to get top N elements(on basis of matches ) from dataframe.

Comment: Yeah sure you can sort with the values and take N number of elements

Comment: Will be great if you can share code for same. I am very new to spark.

Comment: Change the udf to `  val countFreq = udf((value: String) => {`
    `val count = value.split(",").map(_.trim).groupBy(identity).mapValues(_.size)`
    `count.toSeq.sortWith(_._2 > _._2).take(2)`
  })`  this one which returns top 2

Comment: Thanks Shankar. It's really helps.